# Payum Bundle send empty payment - and paypal accept it :) :(

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, payum

I configure Bundle from this example http://payum.forma-dev.com/documentation/0.8/PayumBundle/simple_purchase_examples/paypal_express_checkout

When I go to /payment I am redirected to the PayPal site - but don't have any information about it.

[image]

There is info - you able to see details - but this is not true - i accept payment (without know price and desctiption - and payment succes !?

This Bundle is ready for use or working stage ?

config:

```
payum:
    security:
        token_storage:
            ed\partnerBundle\Entity\PayumSecurityToken:
                doctrine:
                    driver: orm
    contexts:
        frei_payment:
            paypal_express_checkout_nvp:
              api:
                  options:
                      username:  'myusername'
                      password:  'mypass'
                      signature: 'mysing'
                      sandbox: false
            storages:
                ed\partnerBundle\Entity\PaymentDetails:
                    doctrine:
                        driver: orm
```

routing :

```
payment_start:
    pattern:  /payment
    defaults: { _controller: edpartnerBundle:Payment:preparePaypalExpressCheckoutPayment }

edpartner_payment_done:
    pattern:  /payment/done
    defaults: { _controller: edpartnerBundle:Payment:done }
```

actions in Payment Controller:

```
  public function doneAction(){

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $token = $this->get('payum.security.http_request_verifier')->verify($request);

        $payment = $this->get('payum')->getPayment($token->getPaymentName());

        $status = new BinaryMaskStatusRequest($token);
        $payment->execute($status);

        if ($status->isSuccess()) {
            $this->getUser()->addCredits(100);
            $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->set(
                'notice',
                'Payment success. Credits were added'
            );
        } else if ($status->isPending()) {
            $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->set(
                'notice',
                'Payment is still pending. Credits were not added'
            );
        } else {
            $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->set('error', 'Payment failed');
        }

        return $this->redirect('homepage');



    }

    /**
     */
    public function preparePaypalExpressCheckoutPaymentAction(){

        $paymentName = 'my_payment';

        $storage = $this->get('payum')->getStorageForClass(
            'ed\partnerBundle\Entity\PaymentDetails',
            $paymentName
        );

        /** @var \ed\partnerBundle\Entity\PaymentDetails $paymentDetails */
        $paymentDetails = $storage->createModel();
        $paymentDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'] = 'USD';
        $paymentDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = 1.23;
        $storage->updateModel($paymentDetails);

        $captureToken = $this->get('payum.security.token_factory')->createCaptureToken(
            $paymentName,
            $paymentDetails,
            'edpartner_payment_done' // the route to redirect after capture;
        );

        $paymentDetails['INVNUM'] = $paymentDetails->getId();
        $paymentDetails['RETURNURL'] = $captureToken->getTargetUrl();
        $paymentDetails['CANCELURL'] = $captureToken->getTargetUrl();
        $storage->updateModel($paymentDetails);


        return $this->redirect($captureToken->getTargetUrl());



    }
```

Comment: can you please explain how did you manage to send information to PayPal because I am stuck at same point and not able to understand the answer. I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you described is possible, any problems here. To see payment details you have to configure additional fields. There is an example in the [sandbox](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundleSandbox/blob/master/src/Acme/PaypalExpressCheckoutBundle/Controller/PurchaseExamplesController.php#L141)

Comment: ok now it work, but i have in paypal . This is almost end you payment you confirm on site ... - but when i click ok - payment is executed not ask for confirm ?

Comment: and is very strange for my why you dont add details on manual page - http://payum.forma-dev.com/documentation/0.8/PayumBundle/simple_purchase_examples/paypal_express_checkout i think anyone want send empty payment ...

Comment: payum does not abstract payment fields so you still have to know paypal specification. That's how they do that.

Comment: ok i understand but i think in example paypal integration you can add working example, not only partial working. But thanks for good library.

Comment: In fairness this issue seems to be more on the PayPal end that lets this sort of data through rather. Fair enough, Payum could (and possibly should) handle things before this but PayPal should reply with some sort of "invalid fields" response before the transaction is created.

Comment: can someone please explain more about the answer as I am stuck at the same point not knowing what to do. Please