# Not able to send payment to PayPal using Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, payum

I am using Symfony and trying to send payment details to PayPal using [PayumBundle](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle), I got PayumBundle configured and I got it to work until getting redirected to paypal but no payment details were being sent so I searched on line and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277517/payum-bundle-send-empty-payment-and-paypal-accept-it) question in SO and this is the exact blank information screen I am seeing.

Looking at the documentation that answer is pointing to I came up with the following piece of code but when I try to access to route that is calling the following `prepare` Action. I run into an error

```
public function prepareAction(Request $request)
{
    $paymentName = 'paypal';

    $storage = $this->getPayum()->getStorage('ClickTeck\featuresBundle\Entity\Orders');

    /** @var \ClickTeck\featuresBundle\Entity\Orders $paymentDetails */
    $paymentDetails = $storage->create();
    $paymentDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'] = 'USD';
    $paymentDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = 1500;
    $storage->update($paymentDetails);

    $notifyToken = $this->getTokenFactory()->createNotifyToken($paymentName, $paymentDetails);
    $captureToken = $this->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken(
        $paymentName,
        $paymentDetails,
        'payment_done'
    );

    $paymentDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL'] = $notifyToken->getTargetUrl();
    $paymentDetails['INVNUM'] = $paymentDetails->getId();
    $storage->update($paymentDetails);
    return $this->redirect($captureToken->getTargetUrl());

}
```

`Error: Cannot use object of type ClickTeck\featuresBundle\Entity\Orders as array`

I then tried using the following but that leads to another error at paypal end

```
$paymentDetails->PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE = 'USD';
$paymentDetails->PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT = 1500;

This transaction cannot be processed. The amount to be charged is zero
```

This is how my `Order` Entity looks like

```
<?php

namespace ClickTeck\featuresBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Payum\Core\Model\Order as BaseOrder;


/**
 * Orders
 */
class Orders extends BaseOrder
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me find out what is this happening? Its been 2 days I am trying to make the PayumBundle work.

I will really appreciate any help in this. How do I send payment details to PayPal?

Comment: If you don't get help on the bundle that I can post a few snippets showing how to post a payment without a bundle.  Might help you to see what is going on.  Just let me know.

Comment: That will be very kind of you. Please do share

Comment: Finally managed to get it done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148887/setting-up-payum-bundle-with-symfony2-giving-error/28188994#28188994

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of theory:

You messed to different ways of using Payum. First one is completely custom (other words payment specific format). In this case you can use whatever that implements \ArrayAccess interface. The fields names and their values looks same as they are in Paypal docs.

The other way is a thin layer over first one which adds unification. Here you have to use Order model and fill it using available setters. You can still add some specific fields  using setDetails method.

There is a third method: Use your own model (Order\Invoice\Payment you name it) and provide an integration inside Payum.

Now the answer:

How does this `\ClickTeck\featuresBundle\Entity\Orders` model look like? Do you implement OrderInterface or extend ArrayObject from Payum? I guess the first one. If you want to use completely custom solution extend ArrayObject and use it as array. If you need unified variant (you are going to other payment in future) go with Order

Comment: many thanks for giving your feedback. I am going to be honest here, I have never used Payum before, this is my first time so it does not make any sense to me what you said that’s because of my limited knowledge of payum and I thank you for taking out time and explaining it to me. This is what I did before `prepareAction` http://payum.org/doc/0.13/PayumBundle/get_it_started but that was sending blank information to paypal so I changed the code that you see in my question

Comment: I have updated my question and added `Order` Entity so you can see what it looks like. I do not want to use custom format. Just a simple format to send information to paypal thats all and save it in database. Do you have a working example of this somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I finally managed to get it done. and I will appreciate your feedback http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148887/setting-up-payum-bundle-with-symfony2-giving-error/28188994#28188994

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is a simple example of building a Buy Now button to a twig template:

```
{# buynow.html.twig #}
<script 
data-tax="0" 
data-shipping="0" 
data-amount="{{ total }}"
data-quantity="1" 
data-name="Player Registration {{ playDate ~ ' ' ~ player.nameLastPlayer ~ ', ' ~ player.nameFirstPlayer }} {{ player.initialPlayer }}"
data-button="buynow" 
data-custom="My custom information"
src="{{  asset('bundles/ceradteam/js/paypal-button.min.js') }}?merchant=MYMERCHANTID" 
></script>
```

The controller passes in the total amount.  You will need to set your merchant id.

The paypal-button.min.js is a java script file generated by the paypal development site.  It's been awhile since I made mine but it should be straight forward.  And that is all you need for a simple payment.

Note that there is a lot more advanced stuff you can do with paypal but this might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I will dig into it.